# Can I Copy Over React Native Files Initialized Under One Project Over To Another Separately Initialized Project?

Tags: react-native

Let's say I initialize a project under `react-native init <filename>`, installed a bunch of node packages, and added code.

Then separately I initialize a different project under `react-viro init <filename>`, installed a bunch of node packages, and added code.

If I wanted to combine what I created under `react-native init` into what I created under `react-viro init`, is it as simple as copying files over and reinstalling missing node packages into the react-viro project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in the `./src` folder, every file is independent of iOS or Android as part of the JavaScript bundle.

You can simply copy the .js files over and install the node packages in that project.

You probably should not copy any files that are outside the `./src` folder, but I also suspect you wouldn't need to. Files in the Android and iOS folders are rarely touched as they contain operating system config settings and custom modules that you would have wrote in the native languages.

If the file renders JSX, you will be safe to just copy it over and hook it back up.

To state it another way, go into the folder that has `node_modules` in it. You shouldn't copy anything that is in that folder except additional files that you created. This is where people normally create an `src` folder and place all their JavaScript. You probably have an index file in there that points to `./src/app.js` or you may have an `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` that both point to a `./src/app.js`. Anything inside `src` is safe.

That's my best answer without seeing your folders and files.

Comment: You're correct to assume that I would only be transferring files within `./src`. Thanks for putting my mind at ease.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to copy code from one react native project to another, make sure the code you intend to copy is JS and not any native files. Make sure you do register the correct component using AppRegistry. Rest assured you can copy the code from one project to another.

Comment: glad to hear I won't have any issues as long as I stick to js.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a project at folder

```
/my-project/android
/my-project/ios
/my-project/src
```

1. Copy my-project and paste it at your desired folder like

```
/new-my-project
```

2. Change git origin

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/..../**.git
```

3. Open /new-my-project/android in Android Studio, and then rename app/java/com.myproject to com.newmyproject
4. Go to app/build.grade and change com.myproject to com.newmyproject and sync
5. Create firebase project and download google-services.json file and add to new-my-project/android/app
6. Build application, then test application under metro bundler

```
npx react-native start
```

7. Create keystore, test notifications, change base_url_api, test apk etc Android finish now, iOS
8. Update pods on new-my-project/ios

```
pod install && pod update
```

9. open myproject.xcworkspace
10. Change bundle identifier to org.reactjs.native.newmyproject, version to 1.0, build to 1 and desired Display name. Let it index completely
11. Setup in firbase and replace GoogleService-Info.Plist file and Clean build folder in xcode
12. Go to developer.apple.com and create identifiers, APNS certificates, profiles
13. Download certificates from keychain and upload to firebase
14. Build the project in simulator/device and test it.

Done